# Running PHP Script with Windows Task Scheduler

Tags: php, windows-7, scheduled-tasks, command-line-interface

So I found some posts on here about running PHP CLI scripts in the Task Scheduler, and it works like a charm! However, when I normally run the script in command line I output the results to a .log file:

```
ScriptName.php -arg1 -arg2 > log.log 2>&1
```

This doesn't seem to work in the "Add arguments" section of the Task.

I have it where Program/script is: `C:\PHP\php.exe` my argument is  `ScriptName.php -arg1 -arg2 > log.log 2>&1`

Is there something I should be doing different?

Answer (score 0):

Programs run from Scheduled Tasks don't generate any standard output or standard error.  You need to launch a new `cmd` instance:

```
cmd /C C:\PHP\php.exe ScriptName.php -arg1 -arg2 > log.log 2>&1
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I figured. I think I will run the PHP script from a .bat file and generate a log file.

Answer (score 0):

So as a workaround I will just run the script from a .bat file

```
PHP ScriptName.php -arg1 -arg2 > log.log
```

and go from there.